# Angular.js: $http request with JSON as response doesn't work

Tags: json, http, angularjs, request

it's my first app with Angular.js and I've searched so hardly but I can't find a solution:

I've got a search form that makes a request to a web server which retrieves a JSON object; the problem is that this request fails and the error function begins.

Here my code:

```
$scope.queryUser = {};

    $scope.url = "http://xxxx:8080/MyApp/search.do?index=central&query=";

    $scope.search = function(query) {

         $scope.queryUser= angular.copy(query);

        // Create the http post request
        // the data holds the keywords
        // The request is a JSON request.
        $http.post($scope.url +  $scope.queryUser.value).
        success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.status = status;
            $scope.data = JSON.stringify(data);
            $scope.result = data; // Show result from server in our <pre></pre> element
            console.log(data);
        })
        .
        error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
            $scope.status = status;   
            console.log($scope.data);
        });
```

and this is a sample response:

```
{"Workstation, Laptop@Workstation$$Laptop":[{"values":{"instanceid":"OI-4A35F9C31E114FBCB5B7668FC5E1FFB4","classid":"COMPUTERSYSTEM"},"index":"distributed"},{"values":{"instanceid":"OI-6A03793A658E45EE90E589D82B0D0962","classid":"COMPUTERSYSTEM"},"index":"distributed"}]}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of `$scope.data = JSON.stringify(data);` try this: `$scope.data = data;`

Comment: if error is triggered, start by finding out status. Also easy to inspect full request in network tab of browser console. Grab response body and paste in jsonlint.com to make sure it is valid

Comment: The JSON is valid (I use it for another goal). And the code doesn't work neither with $scope.data = data

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: As I said, the error function begins with a status 200. The JSON is correct so I don't know how go on

Answer (score 0):

I understood the problem: this is a problem of domain. Making the request calling the same webservlet it works...calling an external server it doesn't work.

DOH! I'm sorry for the question